# Display recent posts based on post size using IF STATEMENT

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, sidebar

I have a sidebar in wordpress that shows my recent posts. The php code that does this is simply:

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array("numberposts"=>5));
```

I would like to include an IF statement to say:

"If the wordpress post is more than 100 words, display 10 recent posts, else display 5"

I will work out the relevant numbers etc. once I know how this is achieved.

Comment: hmm.. it's something like `if ( strlen($recent_posts> 300 ){//do this}`but you would either have to change `$recent_posts` to `$the_post`. Possibly parse it in a `foreach` loop.

Comment: @yUnoDOWNVOTE I think you mean `global $post` and not `$the_post`. `$recent_posts` is an `array` so you can't do `strlen()` on it.

Comment: Ah, ty. I've scanned through the wordpress php but haven't learned all of the variable names. Thus the foreach to process the array :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the global `$post` to inspect the length of the `post_content` and then set the `$numberposts` accordingly.

```
global $post;
$numberposts = 1; // default number of posts
if ( !empty($post) ){
    $len = strlen( $post->post_content );
    // change $numberposts based on length of $post->post_content
    if ( $len < 300 ){
      $numberposts = 8;
    } elseif ( $len < 500 ){
      $numberposts = 5;
    } elseif ( $len < 800 ){
      $numberposts = 3;
    } else {
      $numberposts = 1;
    }
}
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array("numberposts"=>$numberposts));
```